# Update a progress bar each time a different function runs

Tags: javascript

So I have a progress bar that needs to be updated every time a pin drops on a map but they are in two separate functions. Here is my progress bar:

```
       function moveBar() {
          var barEl = document.getElementById("myBar");   
          var barW = 1;
          var barid = setInterval(frame, 10);
          function frame() {
            //rLength is the length of an array = the total amount of possible pin drops
            if (barW >= rLength) {
              clearInterval(barid);
            } else if (pin drops) {
              barW++; 
              elem.style.width = barW + '%'; 
              }
            }
        }
```

Outside of this function I have a map and another function for dropping a pin on the map that runs about 2 per second but it could take a while to drop all the pins. How would I check if a new pin was dropped and update the progress bar?

edit: I forgot to add that the pin drop is inside the map function and the progress bar is outside both of those... So it looks like this:

```
function progressbar(){}
function map(){
    function pinDrop(){}
 }
```

UPDATE: I have changed the code up a bit but it prints "Undefined". I call checkMarkerCount() every time a pin drops.

```
   var pDrop = 0;
   var dropCounter = pDrop;
   var rLength;
    function checkMarkerCount() {
      if (dropCounter != pDrop) {
        moveBar();
      }
    }
    function moveBar() {
       var barEl = document.getElementById("pro-bar");   
       var barW = 1;
       var barid = setInterval(frame, 10);
       var counter = pDrop; 
      function frame(counter) {
        //rLength is the length of an array = the total amount of possible pin drops
        if (counter >= rLength) {
          clearInterval(barid);
        } else {
          barW = counter; 
          barEl.style.width = barW + '%'; 
          console.log(barW)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please cleanup the question, it's confusing with your old code + the updated code. Also why did you create a `counter` variable? It seems like you could just use `pDrop`.

Comment: And `barid` calls the function `frame` before it is defined.